# Need help pushing info to Ref

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, api, react-hooks

Ive got some advice to useRef to stop continuous api calls triggered by typing in my textarea, but the problem is now that i dont understand useRef that much and dont know how to push the data i typed to the ref. I was using event.target.value for the handleChange function and was wondering if i had to do the same here.

code: https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-moser-ldiw9?file=/src/components/ConvertPlaces.js

Comment: the first answer is good, but tryna find another solution too

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to write complex logic to achieve that. Here's what I usually do.

```js
function MyComponent() {
  const timeout = useRef(null);

  function onChange(e) {
    const value = e.target.value;

    clearTimeout(timeout.current);
    timeout.current = setTimeout(() => {
      // do expensive stuff here
    }, 500);
  }

  return (
    <input onChange={onChange} placeholder="Type something.." />
  );
}
```

What this does? It only does the expensive thing if user hasn't typed for 500ms. You should test different timeout values to find the perfect balance between responsiveness and efficiency.

Comment: it solved part of the problem but i would still like another solution, btw can u help me with another problem? im trying to access an data array in component API data but i dont get why i cant access it. link to array: imgur.com/F3KVxbK